# Remove angular directives in the resulting html tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have code like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        function UsersCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.users = [{name: "Jonh", age: 21}, {name: "Alice", age: 29}];
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in users" class="test">
                Name: {{user.name}}, {{user.age}} years old.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Its running fine. But when you inspect the `li` tag I can see like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users" class="test ng-scope ng-binding" id="anto">
                Name: Jonh, 21 years old.
</li>
```

I doesnt want angular to add `class` by itself.

How shall I prevent this?

Comment: your question is wrong, you are talking about CSS classes not directives, they are 2 completely different things! ps. what is the problem in having such classes appended?

Comment: We have automation written on Selenium , uses classes

Comment: you should not check the exact match of a css class, but instead test if a node CONTAINS a desired class... otherwise your tests will be fragile and hard to maintain ;)